# Register Component not called - react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I have renamed my bundle Identifier from for example `myApp` to `myAppUser`.

and a clean build folder for ios/android, reset cache, remove node_modules then build app again.

**In iOS**
App won't work and I got this error

> myApp has not been registered.
>
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

**In Android**
works very well.

Now in `app.json` file after renamed that contains:

```
{
  "name": "myAppUser" ,
  "displayName": "myAppUser"
}
```

index.js

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
    
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

when I change "**name**" in `app.json` to `myApp` iOS **work** and android **Not work** :\

So how can I solve this issue with the new name `myAppUser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours :) i got the issue! and app works well for both iOS/Android

in the `AppDelegate.m` file should I change the module name to the new name too,

this line

```
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"myAppUser" // here
                                            initialProperties:nil];
```

So if anyone has a clear explanation of why this happens? i just change in ios the build identifier in XCode!